# How can I use subprocess.Popen to run a method in another file while passing in multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, subprocess, popen

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7', 'from some.path.foo import run_setup', 'import ast',
                      'nsvS = ' + str(new_system_variables), 'nsv = ast.literal_eval(nsvS)',
                      'uS = ' + str(user_dict), 'u = ast.literal_eval(uS)',
                      'run_setup(nsv, u)'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above is my code.  I need to have the run_setup method run in the background.  run_setup does in fact run with my current implementation, but none of the values in the dictionaries seem to get passed in.  new_system_variables and user_dict being the 2 dictionaries I'm trying to pass in.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious why don't you just create a python script and call `Popen(['myscript.py'])`?

Comment: Or just use `multiprocessing.Process`, in which case you can just pass the `dict` as an argument to the process function.

Answer (score 4):

Use `multiprocessing` instead;

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from some.path.foo import run_setup

p = Process(target=run_setup, args=(new_system_variables, user_dict))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This gets me halfway there.  Is there a way to redirect stdout and stderr as with subprocess.Popen?  It doesn't look like it can take the same arguments of stdout=someOther.OUTPUT.  Is this where multiprocessing.Pipe comes in?

Comment: Yes you should use a `Pipe` or `Queue` for communication.

Comment: The thing is, `run_setup` is a large method that makes many calls and some of the methods that get called print to the terminal, which I don't want to happen, which was why I was trying to use `subprocess.Popen`.  I'll look for some `Pipe` examples

Comment: If you use the `logging` module for output, you can specify where you want to send the output to; a standard stream, a file but also a `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either, or both, remove the spaces around the =s in you string format or put double quotes around them, the latter is better as it will also cope with any spaces in the parameters.

You *may* also need to have a  `'-c'` option to tell python that the following is a command.

Comment: Don't try to quote things like `str(user_dict)` manually; use `shlex.quote`. Otherwise your code will seem to work, up until someone puts a double quote in a single inside a dict, or a single quote (because that will cause the string's repr to be double-quoted), or possibly other things.